# How to tell Mathematica to solve an equation assuming all solutions are non-negative reals?

Tags: equation-solving, assumptions

The title. I have a system of 6 equations that I want to solve. The system is non-linear. I want to solve it, but I just want Mathematica to give me solutions that are non-negative reals (so no complex numbers, no negative values, etc.). Is there an easy way to do this? Can that be a parameter in Solve? I have tried using Assumptions -> NonNegativeReals, but it does not work. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

[The documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve.html) explains how to specify the domain:

```
Solve[x^2 == 5, x, NonNegativeReals]
(*    {{x -> Sqrt[5]}}    *)
```